# Java jersey 2 json support

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey-2.0

I am trying to create a rest web service which consumes JSON as input. Up to now I have not been able to do so as I get several exceptions. As I am not a maven user, it is so hard to handle dependencies and the documentation is not very helpful. The example that I use as reference is [from mkyong website](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

Please is there anyone who has managed to enable json support in jersey 2 ? Any advice would be extremely helpful as I've reached a dead end. Bellow are my jars and my exception.
[image]

```
avax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$DefaultConfigurationProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:122)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$DefaultConfigurationProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:110)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:153)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:135)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker$Builder.build(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:153)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createInflector(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:128)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createMethodRouter(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:115)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.createResourceMethodRouters(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:309)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RuntimeModelBuilder.buildModel(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:173)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.Routing$Builder.buildStage(Routing.java:196)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:587)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the current stacktrace? It says it's a problem with missing bean validation implementation, but I see you already have the hibernate-validator.

Comment: I do not know. I am confused with the dependencies....

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time figuring out how to get the dependencies for Jersey 2 configured.  I use Maven (recommended) and I know you said you weren't using it but I can show you how my pom.xml is set up and what `mvn dependency:list` says are my dependencies (only relevant part of pom.xml shown):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!--============================= properties =============================-->
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.12</jersey.version>
</properties>
```

And here's what Maven says are my Jersey/Jackson dependencies:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.2:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.3.2:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.3.2:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.3.2:compile
javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.3.0-b10:compile
org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.12:compile
org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.12:compile
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.12:compile
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.12:compile
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.12:compile
org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.12:compile
```

Comment: I mentioned I was only posting a partial pom but good point about removing noise of unrelated dependencies.

Comment: Eventually I did it with maven